# How to retrieve data from SQL Server in C# using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Would you please show me how to retrieve data from SQL Server to C# (Windows Forms application)?

Consider I have a textbox and I need to fill it with data from SQL Server `WHERE 'emp_id = something'` for example, how can I do it without a DataGridView?

Or take this another example:

```
SELECT sum(column) FROM table_name
```

How to get the value of the above command (also without a DataGridView)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. You can use `DataReader` or `DataSet` \ `DataTable`. These are connected and disconnected architectures respectively. You can also use `ExecuteScalar` if you want to retrieve just one value.

Recommendations:

- Enclose `SqlConnection` (and any other `IDisposable` object) in `using` block. My code uses `try-catch` block.
- Always use parameterized queries.

Following is some example code with `DataReader` in case your query returns multiple rows. The code is copied from [here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04).

```
//Declare the SqlDataReader
SqlDataReader rdr = null;

//Create connection
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");

//Create command
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your sql statement", conn);

try
{
    //Open the connection
    conn.Open();

    // 1. get an instance of the SqlDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        // get the results of each column
        string field1 = (string)rdr["YourField1"];
        string field2 = (string)rdr["YourField2"];
    }
}
finally
{
    // 3. close the reader
    if(rdr != null)
    {
        rdr.Close();
    }

    // close the connection
    if(conn != null)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

In case your query returns single value, you can continue with above code except `SqlDataReader`. Use `int count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`. Please note that `ExecuteScalar` may return `null`; so you should take additional precautions.

Answer (score 1):

Filling a Textbox:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("your_connectionstring"))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "select sum(field) from your_table";

        object result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        textBox1.Text = result == null ? "0" : result.ToString();
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();

}
```

for reading more than one row you can take a look at SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use direct database access such as in the System.Data.SqlClient Namespace which is documented here [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basically, look up creating a SQLConnection and SQLCommand and using them to retrieve the data.